# Normalizing URI to make it work correctly with MakeRelativeUri

Tags: .net, vb.net, uri, normalization

```
Dim x AS New URI("http://www.example.com/test//test.asp")
Dim rel AS New URI("http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx.asp")
Console.Writeline(x.MakeRelativeUri(rel).Tostring())
```

In here output is:

```
../../xxx/xxx.asp
```

Which looks correct almost all web servers will process the two of the following as same request:

```
http://www.example.com/test//test.asp
http://www.example.com/test/test.asp
```

What's the best way to fix this behaviour is there any API to do this, or shall manually create a new URI and remove all // in the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that replacing all multi-slashes with one slash in LocalPath portion is the best solution. IIS does so even when passing URL to ASP.net.

Following code will do the trick.

```
x = new Uri(string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}{3}{4}", x.Scheme, x.Host, x.Port, Regex.Replace(x.LocalPath, @"(?<!\:)/{2,}", "/"), x.Query));
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code is not C# but VB, so tags are wrong.

Can you use this code instead, which gives the "correct" url since the // are in the baseuri and will be discarded?

```
var x2 = new Uri(x, rel);
```

Or is it important to get the ../ backtracking in the url?

The MakeRelativeUri function does correct according to the RFC, but it fails according to normal convention. I would suggest you normalize the url yourself, or use my example above if possible.

```
x = new Uri(Regex.Replace(x.OriginalString, "[^:]//", "/"));
```

Comment: That code is very crude hack, as it won't work in several scenarios, most obviously http://example.com/test///xxx secondly even though it's not very well encoded this is a still valid URI: http://example.com/?bla=//Whatup

Comment: Dr.Evil: A valid url depends largely on the webserver interpreting it, and how robust it has decided to be when parsing url's. As the framework doesn't do all cleaning like you want to, then create a "makerelativeurl" function yourself which checks and cleans slashes appropriately. Should you follow the RFC, or handle cases where the url is clearly wrong? .)